# Enable none screen lock

Tags: settings

I cant disable my screen lock , it says it was disabled by administrator , what should I do?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Do you have any VPN configured?

Comment: Or any other device administrator (e.g. an MS Exchange account)?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps have thirselves installed as administrators, which some of them use to block you from the none lock screen option:

[image: example]